# Can multiple users access an open source Shiny Server concurrently?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a program that is built in R and runs on the desktop version of Shiny. I am working on moving the project to a Shiny server. Would it be possible for multiple users to use the program at the same time on the Open Source version of Shiny Server or will there be an issue with concurrent users?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to edit your title or your text so that your question is consistent - right now Alexander's "*No*" answer has opposite meanings depending on if you think it is a response to "can multiple users access..." or "will there be an issue with...".

Comment: I fixed my answer to reflect that. I got the question here and the one on the support website mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

According to [their support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218294957-Is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-concurrent-connections-per-server-for-Shiny-Server-) it can have an unlimited number of users:

> **Yes**. Shiny Server is constrained only by its features.

Comment: You might want to edit - your **no** answers the question in the text which is opposite to the question title.

Comment: By features, do you mean that a shiny server app on a server with let's say 16gb RAM and 2Tb will hold more users than a server on 4gb RAM and 250gb?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a shiny developer but yes. The limitation is that one R process will be used. So if user1 runs some process that takes some time user2's processes will wait for user1 to finish.